# New job. I already hate it and feel completely overwhelmed

Tags: new-job, training

I started a job 2 weeks ago now and i feel completely overwhelmed and don't know what i am doing. In the job i am being trained for i would be working completely on my own for my boss, but right now i am being trained by someone who used to work for the company. (Family member of boss who always trains new employees). I felt like i didn't receive much training seems this person had to fit the training around their schedule, and so we didn't get much in person training time.

I also cannot send out any of my work without it being reviewed so the idea is that i do everything i can, ask her questions via phone or text if i need to, and then she comes in to check my work and we send it out, but the problem is she hasn't really come in much, so those things have gotten left, and sometimes she has taken a really long time to respond to things, and i still don't completely know how to use the system.

I spent the whole day today stressing constantly, anxious, upset, and very hot getting so worked up. I spent an hour trying to figure something out on my own seems she hadn't gotten back, and i have people constantly calling me wanting the things we need to send back to them (which i couldn't seems she wasn't there to review it). I also am sure i did a ton of things wrong and didn't save some stuff i should have.

I ended up leaving work relieved and spent the whole car ride home crying and dreading going back on Monday. I can't even sleep right now with all the worry and stress that i am never going to learn this and will constantly feel this way.

Has anyone else experienced this? I feel bad saying to my boss i don't feel like the person training me is giving me enough training and time and taking a while to get back sometimes at is is family so i feel compromised. I don't know how long to stick it out and try. I seriously already hate it and would feel completely relieved not going back.

Comment: Have you discussed this with your boss or the person who is training you? My advice would be `request more rigorous training and supervision` until they have responded to that. Is your stress related to the lack of training or the job in itself?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: Which industry is this?

Comment: I am an admin assistant

Answer (score 3):

> I started a job 2 weeks ago now and i feel completely overwhelmed and don't know what i am doing.

Sometimes the stress of a new job can do this to you and there is nothing wrong with being honest about it with your boss. However, the way you approach the situation can make a big difference.

> I ended up leaving work relieved and spent the whole car ride home crying and dreading going back on Monday. I can't even sleep right now with all the worry and stress that i am never going to learn this and will constantly feel this way.

It sounds like you have been keeping these concerns and feelings to yourself which build up inside and cause your emotions to explode.

My two cents, you should ask your manager to meet with you so you can talk about your concerns. Rather than telling your manager you feel a certain person is not giving you enough training, you can instead tell your manager you feel you are not getting enough training (keeping the other person out of it).

You don't want to sound like you are complaining, but rather bringing up an issue and looking to work together with your boss to find the solution. Also, try to be specific when you meet with your boss. Let her/him know which areas of training you would like to work on more.

I have had a similar problem in the past. About a month into my job I felt overwhelmed by the project I was on. I talked to my boss about it and it resulted in me getting assistance in the area I was struggling with. Trust me, I had those days too where I was not looking forward to going back to work on Monday. But once I was able to work out the problem I gained confidence and was very happy to continue working there.

Comment: Thank you. I am so paranoid i feel like what if the company we do stuff for gets irritated with me being slow and i lose the contract for my boss. There is only one contract with a company that owns other companies. I guess i am stressing a lot.

Comment: Note that you will feel overwhelmed periodically throughout your career.  Learning to accept it as normal and temporary makes it much less stressful. Focus on getting what you need to not feel stressed, rather than on how much stress you feel. If it was easy, they wouldn't nedd an expert like you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Edgar: it's natural to feel overwhelmed every once in a while. You do need to communicate that you are having difficulties and require additional help.

With that being said, I'd like to look at the situation from another point of view:

**This workplace sounds not only incredibly chaotic, but also very poorly organized.**

In other words, feeling overwhelmed is not only natural for a "newbie", it would be the reaction of a much more experienced person as well. The atmosphere itself sounds more than a little poisonous, with little to no help being offered, no trust given, and yet exposing you to the complaints of customers and others.

That pretty much sounds like you're being set up to fail.

Look at this whole situation as a big learning opportunity. Take the time to absorb as much information as possible, and stop stressing out, because I'm not sure that being fired from a company like that wouldn't be a blessing in disguise. So take a deep breath and try to relax a little bit:

- Are customers angry that their products are not being delivered? There's nothing you can do - your work needs to be approved by someone who isn't actually bothering to do so.
- Are taking 6 hours to figure out how to perform a task that anyone with the necessary training could perform in 20 minutes? You're not to blame - they didn't take the time to train you!

Always politely ask for more training, for more feedback, and inform the responsible parties that work is awaiting review - but that's where your responsibilities end.

Try to detach yourself from the stress and simply focus on what you stand to gain, and what you can walk away from this job with (aka knowledge, experience, and maybe a reference).

You can try toughing it out until the 1 year mark and then finding work at a company that's actually sane. If you break through this barrier, and take control of this position, however, you may find that you can excel by being able to keep your cool and deliver in a chaotic environment where people are used to unreliability.

Answer (score 0):

I always find starting new jobs to be very difficult. I *love* my current job, but the first six months were pretty miserable. I didn't feel like I fit in, it wasn't clear what I was meant to be doing, etc. So this may just be "new job jitters".

In a way, it's a good sign that the reason you're unhappy is that you haven't had enough training, because that is a temporary problem. Even if the training situation doesn't improve, you will eventually learn the job.

Nobody expects you to be good at your job after only two weeks, even if you've had excellent training. So try to go easier on yourself and expect to make mistakes. Talk to your supervisor about getting more training, and be open about how you're feeling (stressed out, worried you'll make mistakes etc.). Maybe they can arrange something. Or maybe they'll tell you you're doing fine, and they know it's going to take time for you to learn the job. Either way, it will probably make you feel better.

Try to imagine how the job will be when you've learned what you need to learn. Do you think you will be satisfied with it? If so then I suggest you stick it out. If not, then maybe this isn't the right job for you, and you subconsciously realise it, and that's the real reason you're stressing out. Either way, try to look at the situation logically -- not ignoring your feelings, but balancing them against the facts.

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to what others are saying a new job should NOT be this overwhelming.

One or more of these things is happening:

1. **Expectations are way too high.**
2. **Training is really poor.**
3. **You are not experienced/smart enough to do the job.**

If you are fairly confident that #3 is not a concern than it is really simple.

Sit down with your boss ASAP and have a plan of things they want you to be able to do for the first week, second week, third week, and so on.  You can map out 4-6 weeks on a one hour call.

From there you can manage the person who is training you.  If they aren't meeting your needs or following the plan then you all three have a call or you talk to your boss about the poor training.  I wouldn't put the trainer on the dismissive until there is a plan - they might be in the same boat as you.

[I have tons of new hires.  We give them basically 2 weeks with very little tasks but maybe 1-2 small things we want them to learn well.  They can start branching out doing more things if they pick those up quick.  Freaking out a new employee is stupid.  90% of the time it is the manager's fault however they could have hired wrong.]

Comment: I think number 2 is the issue. The woman training me isn't training me as well as she could be. The issue i am having is not knowing the job and knowing what to do. If i did i would feel fine

Comment: Then I would get the plan from the manager and make sure she is teaching you according to this.